# Waiting for condition to be true without looping in multithreaded C application

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I am currently using WINAPI with multiple thread.
I have namely three threads. One is the WinMain thread which receives message from Windows Procedure and translates it.
The other two threads are for updating the screen based on event. One is ( runs BackGroundFunc ) looping infinitely and so it plays video in background. Now the other threads ( MenuControlFunc ) waits for signal from WinMain callback function to change any event based objects such as buttons, sliders, etc.

All together I need to have one thread constantly running in back and the menu handler must only execute if user moves their mouse or presses any key.

I have this in callback function.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainHandleMsg(HWND _MainHandle,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lparam){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        //any key pressed or mouse move/click event
            update++;     
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
        case WM_QUIT:
        _exit(0);
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(_MainHandle,uMsg, wParam, lparam);
}
```

The BackGroundFunc() runs without any user response.

```
void *BackGroundFunc(void *vargp){
     while(1){
         /*
          *  
          *
          */ 
     }
}
```

```
void *BackGroundFunc(void *vargp){
     while(1){
         if(update<1)
             continue;
          
         /*  
          *  
          *  Update Menu for no of key events passed
          *
          */       
          update=0; //resetting the update flag
     }
}
```

Now I am just trying to find a way to not loop rather to wait for the update variable to change.
Just like in Serial Handling, the ReadFile function is blocked until the characters arrive at port or like scanf() that waits for line input from stdin.
Or are these functions just looping and checking condition on each loop (Just like what I have been doing)?

Another major problem here I have found is that the main thread is loaded less so that it loops faster and since the Menu handler thread is loaded more it is generally slower and thus as it resets the update flag at the last moment it generally is ignoring any events that may have been passed to program while menu handler was busy with first event.

EDIT: It is partially solved by using circular buffer technique.

Comment: [Condition Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/condition-variables)

Comment: Alternatively: have a look at [`WaitOnAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress) and [`WakeByAddressSingle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-wakebyaddresssingle)/[`WakeByAddressAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-wakebyaddressall). Raymond Chen has a series of articles on using these functions to implement common synchronization mechanisms, start with https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160823-00/?p=94145

Comment: *"The other two threads are for updating the screen"* - Unless you're using DirectX here, that's an invisible synchronization point. The net result being, that spawning a thread is likely a pessimization. *"the ReadFile function is blocked until the characters arrive at port"*. That's not correct. As spelled out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile): *"This function is designed for both synchronous and **asynchronous** operations."* Windows is designed on the core principle, that **all** I/O is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

"Busy waiting" is a cardinal sin in multithreading, as it keeps the CPU occupied doing nothing. In Windows, the best option is usually to use `WaitForMultipleObjects` which can be used to efficiency sleep while waiting for various Windows resources such as threads, mutexes, events, files etc.

So you could create an event (basically a "waitable" boolean) and use that to signal a thread that it is time to do some work. Another similar event could be used to tell the thread that it is time to close the shop, finish everything up and return.